# Undefined property - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, undefined

I'm using Symfony2. My controller finds some values - like categories, created by the and gives them to the template. The problem is that if the user hasn't any created categories yet, I want to display a massage to invite him to create categories.

Here is the code:

```
    if($number_of_categories == 0){
        $newcommer = true;

        //Here the template doesn't need any variables, because it only displays
        // "Please first add some categories"
    } else {
        $newcommer = false;

        //Here the variables, which I give to the template 
        //are filled with meaningfull values
    }

return $this->render('AcmeBudgetTrackerBundle:Home:index.html.twig', array(
        'newcommer' => $newcommer,
        'expenses' => $expenses_for_current_month,
        'first_category' => $first_category,
        'sum_for_current_month' => $sum_for_current_month,
        'budget_for_current_month' => $budget_for_current_month
));
```

The problem is that if the user doesn't have categories I don't have with what to fill the variables, so I have to write something like this:

```
        //What I want to avoid is this: 
        $expenses_for_current_month = null;
        $first_category = null;
        $sum_for_current_month = null;
        $budget_for_current_month = null;
```

just to avoid `Notice: Undefined variable ...`

Is there a cleaner solution to achieve this? There isn't a way to dynamically generate the count of variables, given to the template, is there? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think there are many ways to do what you want, but first, you need to tell us what it is more precisly. Maybe you can render diffrents template whether you have categories or not. Maybe you can just check in your twig template the value of $newcommer, then display what you want. Be more specific on what your goal is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple solution (if I understood your problem) :

```
$template = 'AcmeBudgetTrackerBundle:Home:index.html.twig';

if ($number_of_categories == 0){

    //Here the template doesn't need any variables, because it only displays
    // "Please first add some categories"

    return $this->render($template, array(
        'newcommer' => true,
    ));

} else {

    //Here the variables, which I give to the template 
    //are filled with meaningfull values

    return $this->render($template, array(
        'newcommer' => false,
        'expenses' => $expenses_for_current_month,
        'first_category' => $first_category,
        'sum_for_current_month' => $sum_for_current_month,
        'budget_for_current_month' => $budget_for_current_month
    ));
}
```

And if you want a cleaner solution to manage your Template, you cna use the annotation [@Template()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html) (You just have to return an array to pass to the view) :

```
// ...

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/my_route.html")
     * @Template("AcmeBudgetTrackerBundle:Home:index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
            // ...

        if ($number_of_categories == 0){

            return array(
                'newcommer' => true,
            );

        } else {

            //Here the variables, which I give to the template 
            //are filled with meaningfull values

            return array(
                'newcommer' => false,
                'expenses' => $expenses_for_current_month,
                'first_category' => $first_category,
                'sum_for_current_month' => $sum_for_current_month,
                'budget_for_current_month' => $budget_for_current_month
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't thought of that!